# C# Selenium XPath data from row that contains a span

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, getattribute, xpath-1.0

I am trying to grab data from a table that has two columns. The rows do not have a distinct identifier. But I can search the first column for specifics to find out if I should grab the second column's data.  There are multiple rows in the table although the example below I am just showing one row.

```
<table id="subtotals-marketplace-table" class="a-normal a-align-bottom a-spacing-none a-size-small">
<tbody><tr class="small-line-height">
<td>
    <span>
        Total:
    </span>
</td>
<td class="a-text-right aok-nowrap a-nowrap">
    $12.80
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I need to search for Total: and then grab the dollar amount in the next column.  I've tried multiple iterations of something along these lines but can't seem to find the correct syntax:

```
driver.FindElement(
                    By.XPath(
                        "//*[@id='subtotals-marketplace-table']//td[contains(text(),'Total:')]/following-sibling::td[1]"))
                    .Text;

driver.FindElement(
                    By.XPath(
                        "//table[@id='subtotals-marketplace-table']//td[contains(text(),'Total:')]/following-sibling::td[1]"))
                    .Text;

driver.FindElement(
                    By.XPath(
                        "//table[@id='subtotals-marketplace-table']/tbody//td[contains(text(),'Total:')]/following-sibling::td[1]"))
                    .Text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following Xpath.

```
//table[@id='subtotals-marketplace-table']//tr//td[@class='a-text-right aok-nowrap a-nowrap']
```

OR

```
//table[@id='subtotals-marketplace-table']//tr//span[contains(.,'Total:')]/parent::td/following-sibling::td[@class='a-text-right aok-nowrap a-nowrap']
```

Comment: The first option was too generic because multiple rows had the same class, but the second option worked like a charm!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are different options.

Option 1:

```
//table[@id='subtotals-marketplace-table']//tr[td[normalize-space(.)='Total:']]/td[2]
```

Option 2:

```
//table[@id='subtotals-marketplace-table']//td[normalize-space(.)='Total:']/following-sibling::td
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the text **Total** and then extract the amount associated with **$** you can use the following solution:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='subtotals-marketplace-table']/tbody//td/span[contains(.,'Total:')]//following::td[1]")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

---

### Update

As you are seeing the error as *Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression*, possibly you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(By.XPath("//table[@id='subtotals-marketplace-table']/tbody//td/span[contains(.,'Total:')]/following::td[1]"), "$")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: Thank you but this returned "Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression driver".

Comment: @Roro Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status